# basic haskell : list comprehension for copying an element n times

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a function using list comprehensions that copies an element an amount of times as specified. I'm really stuck on this but I'm trying to

for example

```
copy 2 'a' = aa
```

This is what I have so far:

```
copy2 :: Int->a->[a]
copy2 x y = func1 y [b|b<-[1..x]]
```

where func1 is somehow mapping y to every element of x

It's not a lot but I'm really clueless on this one sorry guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
copy2 qty item = [item|_<-[1..qty]]
```

Comment: Note that the introduced-but-usused variable `i` can lead to compiler warnings. You can avoid that by writing `[ item | _<-[1..qty] ]`, which may also be less confusionsome.

Answer (score 7):

Even though an answer has been accepted, I want to point out that you said something profoundly important in your very question, which could have led you to an answer.

You said:

> ```
> copy2 :: Int->a->[a]
> copy2 x y = func1 y [b|b<-[1..x]]
> ```
>
> where func1 is somehow mapping y to every element of x

If we clean up the phrasing a bit -- I am sure it's what you meant -- we actually want something that `map`s every element of the list produced by the comprehension to the `const`ant value `y`.

Well, making a function that produces a value y for a single x is simple:

```
const y x = y
```

In fact, the function is useful enough that it exists in the Prelude already!

Now we just need to `map` over *every* element of the list.

```
copy2 x y = map (const y) [b | b <- [1..x]]
```

or a bit simplified, to really show how close we are to your original description, (even though I know you needed the list comprehension)

```
copy2 x y = map (\x -> y) [1..x]
```

"map x to y for every x."

So you see, you had it all along.

Comment: Nice way to lead the OP from his initial thoughts to an answer! (albeit an overcomplicated one)

Comment: `map (const y) [b | b <- [1..x]] == [(const y) b | b <- [1..x]] == [y | b <- [1..x]]`.